# AngularJs - Issue with 'merge' function

Tags: angularjs

Friends,

I am using 'merge' function in AngularJs in order to update a JSON from another customized:

```
angular.merge( original, customized );
```

**Original:**

```
{
"CUSTOM_MODULE_CONFIG": {
    "CUSTOMER": {
        "quickSearch": [
            { ... }
        ],
        "monitors": [
            { ... }
        ], 
        "menuNavigation": [
            { ... }
        ]
    }
}}
```

**Customized:**

```
{
"CUSTOM_MODULE_CONFIG": {
    "CUSTOMER": {
        "menuNavigation": [
            { ... }
        ]
    }
}}
```

But finally the Original JSON is updated removing "quicksearch" and "monitors" elements. In other examples (without including arrays) the merge function updates the JSON as expected, without removing any element.

How can I preserve all elements in the JSON?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure, your objects looks fine and I'm getting the correct output...

Comment: What @kukkuz said is right, see console output from https://jsfiddle.net/ztupqjx9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Angular merge Doc (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge)

If you want to preserve original objects, you can do so by passing an empty object as the target: `var object = angular.merge({}, object1, object2).`

Answer (score 0):

Try first parameter `{}`:

```
angular.merge({}, original, customized );
```